# Debugging Ember JS -- Identifying line in code that causes an error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-chrome-devtools, ember-cli

So I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The key provided to get must be a string, you passed undefined

Should be easy enough to fix, if there was any indication of the line in my code that causes that error.

Using the chrome console, I click on ember.debug.js:6254 next to the error, which just shows me the ember code that throws the error.  I can expand the error, but I just get a bunch of functions that can't be clicked on and no indication where they come from.

Can someone please help me figure out how to identify the line in my Ember code that is causing the error.

Comment: Have you tried turning on "Pause on Caught Exceptions" to try to catch it in flagrante delicto?

Comment: Check the callstack of the exception. somewhere is your function

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Pause on Caught Exceptions still just shows me a bunch of Ember code.  The callstack only shows a bunch of ember.debug.js functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a comment but I can't, so here goes:
Iam new to Ember and have been spending quite a long time debugging. Remember that long stack of function calls that chrome's console shows.
Look for anything other than ember.debug.js...especially those marked (anonymous function) and files with names vendor.js or app-name.js

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I was hoping for, but it seems like it's the most accurate and helpful one to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I've gotten this error before. It happens when you call `get()` in any of its forms (`Ember.get()` or `this.get()` or `get(this)`) without a string as the name of the property you want to retrieve.

You should be able to find the source of the error by auditing your application for wherever you call `get()` and making sure you pass the property name as a string. E.g., `Ember.get('model.someProp')` or `this.get('someProp')` or `get(this, 'someProp')`.

Comment: Thanks.  I know how to fix the error.  I was just hoping there was an easier way to identify the problematic line then by going through all the gets in the app.

Comment: Ah. No, not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in software development when debugging your best friends are going to be `console.log()` or `alert()` (in the case of JavaScript). Usually you have to figure out if your getting what ever is that you passing to your function by consolelog everything until you find your bug. Ember sometimes will not tell you what is exactly the error because does not know where exactly is coming from.

...computers are annoying but we love them....

here are some articles from [Mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript) and [Google](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) on how to debug JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was trying to use to track down the bug.  It's just time-consuming because I have a ton of nested routes and was wondering if there was an easier way to determine exactly where it was breaking.

Comment: got you. Well I hope you find something a lot easier, but you learn a lot more this way....

Answer (score 0):

I had a `NULL` value in my database which I wasn't accounting for in my app. In my case, it shouldn't have been `NULL` in the first place, so after giving the record a value in my database the problem disappeared.

I agree the error message is not very helpful.